# Why doesn't setting Time.zone in an application controller affect the application globally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

Following Ryan Bates' instructions on creating a before_filter that sets a time_zone like so :

```
before_filter :set_timezone

def set_timezone
    Time.zone = @current_user.time_zone
end
```

Why does this not affect, let's say, another user using the same application at the same time in different timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because even Rails app can have many threads, each thread maintains its own `zone`. So, from the time you clicked a link and till you got the response body you were exclusively dealing with the same thread (i.e. with the same `zone`).

Comment: Interesting. As an aside, I wonder if this thought has to be re-approached in stateless design with things like Redis, or Node.

Comment: @Trip Node.js id good for long-running huge amount of simple apps, like IM. I don't know what you mean by referring to Redis. It's in-memory storage with persistence. It's good for caching. And by the way, HTTP itself is stateless by design.

Comment: Not really the real reason. Rails does allow multithreaded mode (config.threadsafe!) although is usefulness does vary according to your app and ruby interpreter

Comment: @FrederickCheung Green Ruby treads don't allow you to run threads concurrently. Add here lot's of precautions, automatically disabling of class reloading (i.e., throw away your development mode) and you'll get very unpleasant view. Rails just isn't build for long-running stuff. There are better alternatives for this.

Comment: That's only MRI. And even when threads are green a lot of the time your threads are blocked on io of some sort. Regardless, that's not why setting Time.zone can't affect other requests.

Comment: @FrederickCheung I guess I was too opinionated considering thread==process. Looks like all my gems are made threads-aware where it's needed. Plus I've found this pull request: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6685.

Answer (score 3):

`Time.zone` is not a global setting. There is a shared default setting (which is what `config.time_zone` controls), but calling `Time.zone=` does not set that.

Instead it sets a thead local variable. Subsequent calls to Time.zone from the same thread will read that value, but calls from other threads won't

Since any given thread is only handling one request at a time you can have different users being served requests with different time zones.